# expected type parameter, found struct

Tags: rust, traits

I've encountered a problem which I reduced to the following code:

```
trait Logger {}

struct DefaultLogger;

impl Logger for DefaultLogger {}

struct A<L> where L: Logger {
    logger: Box<L>,
}

impl<L> A<L> where L: Logger {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let logger = DefaultLogger;

        A {
            logger: Box::new(logger),
                          // ^^^^^^ Here is the problem
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::new();
}
```

which produces the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:30
   |
16 |             logger: Box::new(logger),
   |                              ^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `DefaultLogger`
   |
   = note: expected type `L`
              found type `DefaultLogger`
```

When I construct trait `A` in a normal function (like `main`), like I expected it to work. Example:

```
trait Logger {}

struct DefaultLogger;

impl Logger for DefaultLogger {}

struct A<L> where L: Logger {
    logger: Box<L>,
}

fn main() {
        let logger = DefaultLogger;

        let _a = A {
            logger: Box::new(logger),
        };
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
impl<L> A<L> where L: Logger {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let logger = DefaultLogger;

        A {
            logger: Box::new(logger),
        }
    }
}
```

You want to return `A<L>` but you return `A<DefaultLogger>` where you cannot be sure that `L == DefaultLogger`.

To fix that you can provide specialisation that will create method `A::new` only for `DefaultLogger`:

```
impl A<DefaultLogger> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let logger = DefaultLogger;

        A {
            logger: Box::new(logger),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to pass the logger as a parameter, would that work too? Then I wouldn't have to create a new impl block for every subtype of `Logger`.

Comment: This answer saved me so much time debugging and and greatly enhanced my understanding of how generics work in Rust. I know "thank you" comments aren't allowed on SO, but thank you anyway.